# How to limit urls to admin users in Django

Tags: django

I'm currently limiting some urls to only logged-in users in Django by doing the following.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.MainView.as_view()), name='index')
]
```

Is there a way to limit urls to only admin and staff users except for regular users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into these two:

1. [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator or also [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)
2. [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) decorator or also the [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin)

They should be sufficient for your needs. The docs show a few examples that fit your use case.